# Deploy wildfly maven plugin multiple instances

Tags: maven, plugins, wildfly

I have two environments, staging and production. Both are running in the same Wildfly server. There are two instances, standalone and standalone2. So the difference is the port and the directory.

When I deployed my application with Wildfly Maven Plugin on staging environment, I couldn't find the application's war. I think the content is generated in $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone2/data/content, but I can't find as well. Maybe it was removed after the deploy.

How can I copy the war archive, which is running in the staging environment, to the production environment?

A piece of my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly-user}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
```

I know I can add another profile, but I wouldn't like to compile again after testing in staging environment. I wanna just copy the WAR tested.

Comment: What does your pom configuration look like?

Comment: You can have multiple executions and a specific configuration for each one but I guess you don't want to deploy the same WAR to both server at the same time.

Comment: You can find you WAR/EAR in your content directory but with no extension try to match the size then open it with 7zip or sth like that to know that was the correct one. Finally you must rename and deploy it from web console of your production env.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy with the maven wildfly plugin, you can see the deployed components through the Management Console (typically on port 9990), but as far as I know, you cannot copy it.
You need to deploy it separatly to the other instance with the maven wildfly plugin again.
If you want to copy it manually, you will first need to remove the deployed component through the management console and then copy the war archive to the folder standalone\deployments and standalone2\deployments.

Comment: I see you edited your post and you don't want to recompile after it has been tested. I understand that, and then I would recommend to release your project before deploying to staging (using the maven release plugin: this will create a new version and upgrade the snapshot version). If the tests are then succesful, you can rebuild the released version without having to worry about possible changes in your rebuild.